# React - How do you loop in switch case to collect data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

I am building a form, and there is a data array containing a certain number of elements that i would like to loop through to fill up. The data looks something like this

```
 data: [
    {
      nestedField1: { id: 1, x: "x1" },
      nestedField2: ["", "", ""],
    },
    {
      nestedField1: { id: 2, x: "x2" },
      nestedField2: ["", "", ""],
    },
    {
      nestedField1: { id: 3, x: "x3" },
      nestedField2: ["", "", ""],
    }]
```

I am using state steps to transit from one form page to another. I would like to repeat the same form page in case 4 for 3 times. May i know what is the proper way to do a loop within a switch?
I have something like that and the loop for case 4 is not working

```
var numberOfWords = data.length;
switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return <FirstComponent 
           nextStep={this.nextStep} />;
      case 2:
        return (
          <SecondComponent
            prevStep={this.prevStep}
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
          />
        );
      case 3:
        return (
          <ThirdComponent 
           prevStep={this.prevStep}
           nextStep={this.nextStep} 
         />
        );
      case 4:
        while (numberOfWords--) {
          return (
            <FourthComponentInLoop
              prevStep={this.prevStep}
              nextStep={this.nextStep}
              values={values}
            />
          );
        }
      case 5 + numberOfWords:
        return <FifthComponent />;
    }
```

NOTE : I have tried map but i was unable to get it working. Otherwise I wouldn't be asking lol.

I need to render individual components ON DIFFERENT PAGES. So returning an array will not work because all the components will be clustered in one page

Comment: you can use `map`

Comment: [Rendering Multiple Components - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temp array like so.

```
case 4: 
 let tempArr = [];
 while(..){tempArr.push(<AnyReactComponent>)}
 return tempArr;
```

Comment: This will render multiple copies of the same component in one page. I am looking to render the same component on different pages

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for this ? Hard to understand how you want the interaction across pages.